# Finding the GUID of a specific folder

Tags: windows-7

How do I find the GUID of any folder on my C:\ drive? I want my Windows Explorer on Windows 7 to open in a folder called "Temporary Downloads", and it seems I need the GUID to accomplish this.

Comment: What makes you think you need a GUID?  `explorer C:\path\to\folder` doesn't work?

Comment: I'm trying to get my Windows Explorer to open up at C:\Temp Downloads. This link suggests I need the GUID to accomplish this. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17415/set-the-windows-explorer-startup-folder-in-windows-7/

Comment: If Win7 is like XP (and it probably is), you only need a GUID for "special folders" which don't have a normal path (eg. `c:\windows`) in the filesystem - so you shouldn't say "on my C drive", but rather "in the shell namespace".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a GUID, you can just pass the path as an argument, surrounded in quotes. For example, to set the default to `C:\Temporary Downloads`, follow the directions in the How-To Geek article you mentioned, but paste this in the "Target" field:

`%windir%\explorer.exe "C:\Temporary Downloads"`

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking for the `Temporary Internet Files` folder, [this article](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/10/where-is-the-temporary-internet-files-folder-located-in-windows-7/) suggests that it is located at

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

No GUID needed for that one.

I can't find a `Temporary Downloads` folder on my system.